# Mysql error in a simple piece of code

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a simple database going so i can practive my PHP, i'm copying this from a book, here's the code:

```
USE testeDB;

CREATE TABLE test(
id INT not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR (25),
telefone VARCHAR (12);
PRIMARY KEY (id),
);

INSERT INTO teste VALUES ('', 'Joaquim', '1111');
INSERT INTO teste VALUES ('', 'Carlos', '2233');
INSERT INTO teste VALUES ('', 'Antonio', '3333');
INSERT INTO teste VALUES ('', 'Roque Santeiro', '6969');
```

I used phpmyadmin to create the databse, but when i run that code to create the table i get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

It must be something simple, but i can't figure what is the problem.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Test incrementally - run only the `CREATE TABLE` statement first, then each statement individually.

Comment: Table name is `test`, but then your SQL tries to insert into `teste`?

Comment: Table name ithat you create is 'test' and then you insert values into 'teste'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

syntax error on creating of table

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id INT not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR (25),
telefone VARCHAR (12),  -- <=== here
PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

since the id is `auto incremented` you can do it this way,

```
-- pass NULL value to column ID since the server automatically
-- assigns the value of the ID for it. also notice that you have specify 
-- column ID as the primary so it won't have duplicated value for ID
-- NULL is NOT THE SAME as empty string
-- NULL is NOTHING (or unknown) and 
-- Empty string is a zero-length string
INSERT INTO test VALUES (null, 'Joaquim', '1111');    
INSERT INTO test VALUES (null, 'Carlos', '2233');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (null, 'Antonio', '3333');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (null, 'Roque Santeiro', '6969');
```

OR

```
-- explicitly supply the column you want to insert value
INSERT INTO test (nome, telephone) VALUES ('Joaquim', '1111');
INSERT INTO test (nome, telephone) VALUES ('Carlos', '2233');
INSERT INTO test (nome, telephone) VALUES ('Antonio', '3333');
....
```

Answer (score 3):

```
telefone VARCHAR (12);
```

should be

```
telefone VARCHAR (12),
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another problem with this is:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id INT not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR (25),
telefone VARCHAR (12);
PRIMARY KEY (id),
);

INSERT INTO teste VALUES ('', 'Joaquim', '1111');
INSERT INTO teste VALUES ('', 'Carlos', '2233');
INSERT INTO teste VALUES ('', 'Antonio', '3333');
INSERT INTO teste VALUES ('', 'Roque Santeiro', '6969')
```

The `teste` doesn't exist, you need to use test (from the CREATE TABLE syntax), to insert it looks like:

```
   INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Joaquim', '1111');
    INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Carlos', '2233');
    INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Antonio', '3333');
    INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Roque Santeiro', '6969')


-- Not need to put the '' either since the value is auto incrementing (more here:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)
```